# Calculate motor flux of a PMSM

Tags: motor, magnetics, magnetic-flux, pmsm

I am struggling with the calculation of the motor flux for a RPX22-042V24 PMSM. I know back EMF, Torque constant and several other values from the [datasheet](https://www.electrocraft.com/files/downloads/Datasheets/bldc/RPX22-DataSheet-US.pdf). But I found different ways to calculate the flux and I am not sure if its correct to use back EMV in V/kRPM or V/RPM.

With the equation at the end of [this page](https://de.mathworks.com/help/sps/ug/parameterize-a-permanent-magnet-synchronous-motor.html) I get a flux of 4.15 mWb. Does this value make sense for this parameter?

Comment: I found two ways for calculating the magnetic flux of a motor, but the results are very different. Maybe someone knows why?
Option 1: According to the formula in the end of this page https://de.mathworks.com/help/sps/ug/parameterize-a-permanent-magnet-synchronous-motor.html
flux1=Kt/N=16.6mNm/A/4pole pairs=4.15mWb 
with Kt = torque constant
Option 2: According to the formula from the SPMSM page https://de.mathworks.com/help/mcb/ref/surfacemountpmsm.html
flux2=(2/3)*Kt/N=(2/3)*16.6 mNm/A/4pole pairs=2.77mWb

The flux's unit is in both cases correct but whats the reason for the factor2/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody faces the same problem:

In my case the datasheet's values must be converted from line to line to phase values and the formula for flux1 is for a BLDC.
For a PMSM the formula for flux2 = (2/3)*Kt/N=(2/3)*16.6 mNm/A/4pole pairs suits better. The other one (via back-EMF) proposed in the link can also be used with a slightly different result.

https://de.mathworks.com/help/mcb/ref/surfacemountpmsm.html